# Inverse of a matrix expression after SVD

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, svd

Let: $UDV^T$ be the SVD decomposition of $A$; $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ and $I_n$ the identity matrix

Why is the following true?

$(VD^2V^T+\lambda I_n)^{-1} = V(D^2+\lambda I_n)^{-1}V^T$

Comment: As $U$ and $V$ are orthogonal (by the definition of SVD) you can use the fact that $U^T=U^{-1}$ (and the same with $V$) and then you can expand/cancel/rearrange the lhs forcing the $V$ outside of the parenthese

Comment: I figured it out now, using your tip, and the fact that $I_n = VV^T$!